# I wish to clone a git repository to a new computer using solely execSync or things possible from eval

Tags: node.js, git, pm2

I've got a Discord Bot running on my home PC, this has served as a server for me for ages. Now, I don't have SSH into it, and I'm going to be leaving for a hefty vacation, but I want to keep running it on said home PC, yet at the same time, edit it from another computer, then push to the primary one. I've got a *mediocre* understanding of git and it's honestly confusing me here, this bot allows me to run `eval()` directly so I can pass commands to it quite easily, but how do I get it to:

- Update two of the files in the NJS Process' directory remotely.
- Force a restart on PM2.

I don't even know what the correct way to address any of this is, any help is greatly appreciated, and I know that it seems like I haven't done my homework but trust me my brain is on the verge of corruption here.

Thanks in advance!

Edit: I have succeeded in the PM2 Part of the process. Still, git is confusing me.

Comment: What your talking about is Continuous Integration. Don't roll your own, using something like [Jenkins](https://www.jenkins.io/) or [Travis](https://travis-ci.org/)

Comment: If you're running on a desktop PC, it will be much easier to just set up some remote desktop thing to manage things from afar. Chrome Remote Desktop has proven reliable. https://remotedesktop.google.com/

Comment: Try VNC or TeamViewer. It allows to remotely login and control any machine from anywhere... on any device (pc, mac, tablet, mobile phone)